# Convert df into one column on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to convert a whole df into one column?
From this

```
c1 c2 c3
1  5  9
2  6  10
3  7  11
4  8  12
```

To this

```
C4
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: Check `stack` or `melt`

Comment: `df.melt(value_name='C4')['C4']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can also try with `unstack`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.unstack().values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quang above is correct:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2, 3, 4], 'c2':[5,6,7,8], 'c3':[9,10,11,12]})
df = df.melt(value_name='C4')['C4']
df
```

Output of a Panda's Series:

```
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     10
10    11
11    12
Name: C4, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case you can use:

```
a,b,c=list(df.values)

df=pd.DataFrame(a+b+c)
```

Comment: AFAIK list() has quite a bit of overhead in this case and copies the data. Preferred would be df.to_numpy().T.ravel() or even the built-in methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `explode()`

```
df['col4'] = df.to_numpy().tolist()
df['col4'].explode().reset_index()[['col4']]
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(df,'F'),columns=['C4'])
```